# Calculating distances but the result is - 2147483648

Tags: c++, arrays, distance

Below is the code to calculate the distance

```
// creating array of cities
double x[] = {21.0,12.0,15.0,3.0,7.0,30.0};
double y[] = {17.0,10.0,4.0,2.0,3.0,1.0};

// distance function - C = sqrt of A squared + B squared
```

Comment: You realize `(x[c1] - x[c2] * x[c1] - x[c2])` is not the same as `(x[c1] - x[c2])*(x[c1] - x[c2])`? And the last one is the one you want.

Comment: `(x[c1] - x[c2] * x[c1] - x[c2]) + (y[c1] - y[c2] * y[c1] - y[c2]))` - what do you anticipate that this line of code will do?

Comment: Beat me to that by like 2 seconds.

Comment: Did you compile this with warnings enabled? `int z = sqrt ...` is odd - why would it return an int?

Comment: I'm going to go out on a limb and say that a negative number is being passed to `sqrt` due to your precedence problem, and causing it to mess up and return an undefined result (ie. your largely negative number).

Answer (score 4):

One issue is that the [order of operations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations) is messing you up (multiplication is done before subtraction)

Change

```
(x[c1] - x[c2] * x[c1] - x[c2]) + (y[c1] - y[c2] * y[c1] - y[c2])
```

to

```
((x[c1] - x[c2]) * (x[c1] - x[c2])) + ((y[c1] - y[c2]) * (y[c1] - y[c2]))
```

I would also recommend, just for clarity, doing some of those calculations on separate lines (clearly that's a style choice that I prefer, and I'm sure some would disagree).  It should make no difference to the compiler though

```
double deltaX = x[c1] - x[c2];
double deltaY = y[c1] - y[c2];

double distance = sqrt(deltaX * deltaX + deltaY * deltaY);
```

In my opinion that makes for more maintainable (and less error prone, as in this instance) code.  Note that, as rewritten, the order of operations does not require extra parentheses.

Comment: He also needs to not be assigning this value to an int.  sqrt will not return an integer value(and on top of that is function is supposed to return a double yet z is an int)

Comment: @jzworkman: Good observation in relation to the original post, though I wonder if `int` is a typo since `sqrt` returns a `double`, and so does his sample function.

Comment: I agree it could be a typo, just wanted to point that out in case it wasn't(as that would definitely break his code as well). Its also interesting that he returns the z at all since he uses cout to display the result within the dist function and then never uses the return value

Comment: Agreed, it'd be better not to have that cout there since the function name is `dist` not `displayDist`

Answer (score 0):

Remember operator precedence: `a - b * c - d` means `a - (b * c) - d`.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want

`(x[c1] - (x[c2] * x[c1]) - x[c2])`

or

`((x[c1] - x[c2]) * (x[c1] - x[c2]))`

`(x[c1] - x[c2] * x[c1] - x[c2])` will be similar to `(x[c1] - (x[c2] * x[c1]) - x[c2])` because `*` has higher precedence than `-`.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to go ahead and fix a couple of issues:

```
 // creating array of cities
double x[] = {21.0,12.0,15.0,3.0,7.0,30.0};
double y[] = {17.0,10.0,4.0,2.0,3.0,1.0};

// distance function - C = sqrt of A squared + B squared

double dist(int c1, int c2) {
   double z = sqrt (
        ((x[c1] - x[c2]) * (x[c1] - x[c2])) + ((y[c1] - y[c2]) * (y[c1] - y[c2])));
   return z;
}  

void main()
{
  int a[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
  execute(a, 0, sizeof(a)/sizeof(int));


    int  x;

    printf("Type in a number \n");
    scanf("%d", &x);


    int  y;

    printf("Type in a number \n");
    scanf("%d", &y);

 double z = dist (x,y);
 cout << "The result is " << z;
}
```

This fixes the unused return value, and also fixes the order of operation, and incorrect variable type of int.